# Instantiated entities don't collide with each other

Tags: unity, collision-detection, physics, entity-component-system, unity-dots

I've started to learn DOTS some day ago, and decided to create a simple project. When I added some simple physics to the game I faced the problem. I added one object on the scene and another instantiated from a resource as a prefab (prefab contains physics shape and physics body), but they didn't collide and just go through. When I tried to place both objects in the scene they work perfectly. Then I tried to instantiate them both and got nothing, I mean they didn't collide... Maybe I miss something? I couldn't find any explanation for this in the Unity Physics doc.

Tried in Unity 2021.1 and 2020.3

Box on the scene configuration:

[image: Game object on the scene]

Sphere prefab configuration:
[image: Sphere prfab]

Spawn object code:

```
        var world = World.DefaultGameObjectInjectionWorld;
        var entityManager = world.EntityManager;

        var settings = GameObjectConversionSettings.FromWorld(world, null);
        _entityPrefab = GameObjectConversionUtility.ConvertGameObjectHierarchy(_playerPrefab, settings);

        Entity player = entityManager.Instantiate(_entityPrefab);
        entityManager.AddComponent<PlayerMovementComponent>(player);
        entityManager.SetComponentData(player, new PlayerMovementComponent()
        {
            Speed = 10f
        });
        entityManager.SetComponentData(player, new Translation()
        {
            Value = new float3(.5f,0f,.5f)
        });
```

Comment: Did you look at both entities in the entity debugger? Are there any obvious differences between them?

Comment: @Philipp thank you, looks like I found the problem, but I don't know how this happened... The entity from the scene has a physics collider component, but spawned hasn't.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution at the Unity's forums old thread, here's the [link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/converting-a-prefab-with-collider-then-instantiating-it-at-runtime-with-unity-physics.787988/#post-5252447). Long story short I passed null as the second parameter when called GameObjectConversionSettings.FromWorld function. But you MUST pass any blob store, you can create a new one or you can get it from the world, by calling this script:

```
var conversionSystem = world.GetExistingSystem<GameObjectConversionSystem>();
```

So final spawn method should look like that:

```
    var world = World.DefaultGameObjectInjectionWorld;
    var entityManager = world.EntityManager;
    var blobStore = new BlobAssetStore();
    var settings = GameObjectConversionSettings.FromWorld(world, blobStore );
    _entityPrefab = GameObjectConversionUtility.ConvertGameObjectHierarchy(_playerPrefab, settings);
    Entity player = entityManager.Instantiate(_entityPrefab);
```

or like that if you want to use blobStore from the world:

```
    var world = World.DefaultGameObjectInjectionWorld;
    var entityManager = world.EntityManager;
    var conversionSystem = world.GetExistingSystem<GameObjectConversionSystem>();
    var settings = GameObjectConversionSettings.FromWorld(world, conversionSystem.BlobAssetStore);
    _entityPrefab = GameObjectConversionUtility.ConvertGameObjectHierarchy(_playerPrefab, settings);
    Entity player = entityManager.Instantiate(_entityPrefab);
```